# Incorrect host on redirect when using Grails on Tomcat6 with virtual host

Tags: tomcat, grails, redirect, virtualhost

I've got a tomcat 6 installation running two virtual hosts, to have two applications as root. Nevermind that.
It's a very basic setup:

server.xml

```
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="hostA">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      <Host name="hostA"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
  <Context path="" docBase="Invoices-0.1.war" reloadable="true" useHttpOnly="true"/>
      </Host>
      <Host name="hostB" appBase="webappsTwo" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
        <Context path="" docBase="Engine-0.1.war" reloadable="true" useHttpOnly="true"/>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
```

It's hard to make it simpler than that.

The issue I've got, is that whenever a redirect is performed on the engine app on hostB it will send wrong URL.
It always points to `http://hostA/Engine/controller/action` when it should point to `http://hostB/controller/action`.

At first I thought it was a problem with Config.groovy and the server URL. I've double checked, it was ok. I've tried removing the config option but still no joy.
The second app, on hostA works fine.

I've also went through the code to make sure hostA is not mentioned there, but found nothing.

I'm lost now, any advice?

EDIT:
I've tried setting `grails.serverURL` again to point to the correct domain and use `absolute:true` in redirects, but it still redirects me to incorrect host. I'm lost even more than before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this happens to often. 
After changing settings in grails I've incorrectly deployed my webapp on tomcat, so none of the changes were propagated. Dammit. I forgot to remove the old directories in webapps directory. dammit.